# Why older version of package repositories of Ubuntu don't get updated?

Tags: apt, updates, package-management, repository

Suppose my Ubuntu version is Natty and I want to install the latest nodejs using apt-get. However, the latest nodejs is only available in the package repository of Quantal.(see http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=nodejs&searchon=names&section=all), which force me to either update my operating system to Quantal or build the latest nodejs from its source tarball.

The building script of nodejs on Natty has no difference from that on Quantal . Why the maintainers of Ubuntu package repositories don't even try to keep package repositories of Natty up with Quantal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Natty is [End of Life](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#End_of_Life_.28EOL.29).

That means it is no longer a supported version of Ubuntu, therefore there are no updates issued for it, and the standard repositories for it were disabled and moved elsewhere in a read-only capacity, usually useful only for upgrading from release-to-release to get to a stable release.

That's why you're not going to see updated software on Natty.  Ever.  Unless you build it from source manually.

Answer (score 1):

> Why the maintainers of Ubuntu package repositories don't even try to keep package repositories of Natty up with Quantal?

We do. We call it Quantal.